Does it make sense to use karpenter when not automatically consolidating
I'm trying determining whether karpenter makes sense when you aren't automatically consolidating with:
consolidationPolicy: WhenUnderutilized
I understand that if consolidation is happening, that I could see a great cost benefit.
However if I'm not using consolidation (as some of my workloads just can't be stopped and restarted), then is there still a value in Karpenter?
Without auto-consolidation, I could see a large node spinning up and the workload completing, but if there is still a single long lived app there, that node would continue to run and eat a lot of cost. now if that node is even larger than what I would have used in my managed nodepool, then it could cost me more.
I'm starting to feel Karpenter may not be the single solution to replace self managed nodes and managed nodes all together, but I could be wrong.
Any info is appreciated. Thanks.
